# How reference a function from TemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I cannot figure out to call something from an expression generated with TemplateHaskell. Let's say I want to use ":" operator to cons list.
I saw syntax `'(:)` but it is not working for me.
Also I tried to lookupNameValue and wrap `mkName ":"` into `(AppE (VarE (mkName ":"))`, but none of above is working...

```
{-# LANGAUGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGAUGE TemplateHaskellQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax as S
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote

useColon :: Q [Dec]
useColon = do
  let fName = mkName "f"
  pure [ FunD fName 
         [Clause []
          (NormalB (InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 1)))
                   '(:)
                    (Just (ListE [])))) []]
  ]
```

> ```
> • Syntax error on '(:)
>   Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell or TemplateHaskellQuotes
> • In the Template Haskell quotation '(:)    | 36 |                                '(:)    |                                ^^^^
> ```

Comment: Why not just use something like `[e| 1:[] |]`?

Answer (score 0):

I made a type in TH extension and I had to use ConE instead of VarE

```
useColon :: Q [Dec]
useColon = do
  let fName = mkName "f"
  pure [ FunD fName [Clause []
                     (NormalB (InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 1)))
                               (ConE '(:))
                               (Just (ListE [])))) []]]
```